# Conditionally enable/disable button control?

Tags: office-js

I've looked through the docs at https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/control but can't find anything.

I want to disable a button on the ribbon unless a certain condition is met. The condition would be the presence of a custom property on the selected mail item.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*IMPORTANT UPDATE:*

[Enabling and Disabling Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands) is now available in Preview for Excel. As part of [AddinCommands 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/add-in-commands-requirement-sets), this feature supposed to be available for all Office products in the future.

*THE OLD ANSWER:*

> Can it be done?

Nope.

[Add-in commands for Outlook](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook?product=outlook) doesn't support dynamic enabling/disabling ribbon items. [Activation rules](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/manifests/activation-rules?product=outlook) are for context type of Outlook add-ins, which is currently **not** recommended way to write add-ins and they are not accepted by Office store.

[Add-in commands for Excel, Word, and PowerPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) doesn't support dynamic enabling/disabling ribbon items either.

According to documentation on [Control element](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/control) of the Manifest none of the available controls have "enable/disable" attribute or tag.

If this is something you would like to see in upcoming releases, you may post/upvote your suggestion at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Is same applicable for Word Add-ins?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanR I have modified my answer per your request. The feature you are asking about related to the Manifest  and applicable for all Office products line.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: Its in preview for Excel now
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands

Comment: @SohailZ Thanks a lot for the tip; I have updated the answer. Best regards.